# First Generation Macbook Air Firmware Locked

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a first generation Macbook Air, and the firmware is locked.
I tried taking it to an Apple store, and they recommended swapping the Logic Board.
Is there anything I can do to reset the password?

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple's online support article (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2391) simply states to schedule an appointment at an Apple retail store or an Apple authorized service provider.

Comment: What do you mean by "the firmware is locked"? Do you mean an EFI password, or something else?

Comment: It can't boot off the hard drive, or any other device for that matter. Holding down the Option key brings me to a prompt with a lock pad asking for a password.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it using MacOS installer. There is 'Firmware password' application in Utilities (top menu). Just use it.

Comment: In order to boot to the Installer though you have to either set it as the Startup Disk via System Preferences in your OS or you have to boot to it using a modifier key at startup.  The firmware password prevents modifier keys from working unless you enter the password.  From the sound of it his machine isn't booting to his OS for whatever reason so the System Preferences option would be out as well. The usual hardware tricks to get around a firmware password are also unavailable with it being a MacBook Air.